# show Time Field in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In Component, I want to show Accordion's label as Time field. Also, I have the same Time field inside.. Both are not showing correctly as in Record page.

I have also tried `lightning:formattedTime` inside, but result are same.

> lightning:formattedTime

[image]

Below is my component piece,

```
<lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Agens}" var="Agenda">
        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!Agenda.Id}" objectApiName="Agenda__c">
            <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="{!Agenda.Time__c}">
                <div class="slds-box slds-form_horizontal slds-form slds-grid slds-wrap">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Time__c" />
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
                </div>
            </lightning:accordionSection>
        </lightning:recordViewForm>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:accordion>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why its not working, even in my Dev org Time is not displayed, but I found a workaround for it, check if it works for you.

> Event using `lightning:outputField` with `lightning:recordEditForm` does not work.

Basically I used `lightning:recordEditForm` and `lightning:inputField` with attribute disabled="true".

**So you must implement JS validation for it to be readonly.**

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="0012800000IOph3" objectApiName="Account">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Time__c" disabled="true"/>
        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```