# Pass OutputField values to Controller Lightning

Tags: lightning

I want to pass "ID" Parameter as componentDef for navigateToComponent - This ID comes from lighting:outputField tag.. Below is the component code,

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Agens}" var="Agenda">

   <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="{!Agenda.Name}" > 
   <lightning:recordViewForm  recordId="{!Agenda.Id}" objectApiName="Agenda__c" aura:id="ag">           
           <div class="slds-box slds-form_horizontal slds-container--medium slds-form slds-grid slds-wrap">                   
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" aura:id="client"/>
           </div>  
           <div>
                <li class="minli"> <h3><a onclick="{!c.navigateToSurvey}" style="width:100%;">Click here to take Survey</a></h3> </li>
           </div> 
   </lightning:recordViewForm >
  </lightning:accordionSection>
 </aura:iteration>
```

JS

```
navigateToSurvey : function(component, event, helper) 
{
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        var nameField = component.find("client");
        var expname = nameField.get("v.value");

        evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:Lightning_Survey",
        componentAttributes: 
            {
                Id : expname 
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
},
```

I am facing error

> [component.find(...).get is not a function

with this.. Can anyone explain whats the issue?

Comment: what is a question? are you facing any error or exception ? maybe unexpected behavior ?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskiy , sorry for not making it clear. Just updated the error I am facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output field is inside `aura: iteration`. That means there can be multiple field having aura:id 'client'

So `component.find("client");` returns an array instead of just a single output field. And as the array does not have `get` you face the error.

A quick way would be to add an `id` to the anchor tag and then use the same in your `navigateToSurvey` method

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Agens}" var="Agenda">

   <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="{!Agenda.Name}" > 
   <lightning:recordViewForm  recordId="{!Agenda.Id}" objectApiName="Agenda__c" aura:id="ag">           
           <div class="slds-box slds-form_horizontal slds-container--medium slds-form slds-grid slds-wrap">                   
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" aura:id="client"/>
           </div>  
           <div>
                <li class="minli"> 
                <h3><a onclick="{!c.navigateToSurvey}" id="{!Agenda.Id}" style="width:100%;">Click here to take Survey</a></h3>
                </li>
           </div> 
   </lightning:recordViewForm >
  </lightning:accordionSection>
 </aura:iteration>
```

JS:

```
navigateToSurvey : function(component, event, helper) 
{
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        var agendaId = event.target.id;

        evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:Lightning_Survey",
        componentAttributes: 
            {
                Id : agendaId 
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
},
```

Comment: Hi Pranay, It worked :) One more question - I am showing "Name" as label for lightning:accordionSection above. If I use any other custom fields, values are not showing. Is it expected.?

Comment: are you querying other fields? does those fields exists in v.Agens?

Comment: Yes, {!Agenda.Time__c} is the field I have. If possible, please have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247833/show-time-field-in-lightning-component/247844#247844 :) Thanks!